# Unable to add controller after moving project to VS2013

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, visual-studio, visual-studio-2013

I have just moved my MVC project from one machine that was running VS2012 to my new machine running VS2013. Everything works when I open/build my project on the new machine however when trying to add a controller (by right clicking on the controllers folder and clicking Add>New Controller') I get the following error:

[image]

I have tried restarting everything, cleaning the code etc. but can't find out how to fix this issue. If I manually add a new item and then select MVC Controller Class it works fine.

Comment: Show your code also..

Comment: Which bit of code? The dialogue where I normally pick the Model/Context doesn't even open, the error gets thrown before this, so which bit of code would it be tied to?

Answer (score 0):

You did say which version of ASP.NET MVC you were using in VS 2012 but below is from the Visual Studio compatibility guidelines, which may help if you were using MVC 3.

Visual Studio 2010 SP1 supports only MVC 2 and MVC 3, Visual Studio 2012 supports only MVC 3 and MVC 4, and Visual Studio 2013 supports only MVC 4. For information about how to automatically upgrade from MVC 2 to MCV 3, see ASP.NET MVC 3 Application Upgrader. For information about how to manually upgrade from MVC 2 to MVC 3, see Upgrading an ASP.NET MVC 2 Project to ASP.NET MVC 3 Tools Update. For information about how to manually upgrade from MVC3 to MVC 4, see Upgrading an ASP.NET MVC 3 Project to ASP.NET MVC 4. If your project targets the .NET Framework 3.5 SP1, you must retarget it to use the .NET Framework 4.